# Is a ViewController okay to use for making a loaderView?

Tags: ios, uiview, loader

I'm making a loader for my app, and can't figure out how to do it. I have no experience with using .xib. Can I just make it in storyboard as a viewcontroller with a view, or is that considered bad practice?

Comment: Yes you can take.

Comment: Ideally you should do it on xib as it would be easy to in terms of reusability and ease of use and implementation.

Comment: When I remove the view from the superview? Is the view then deallocated? I don't want the animation in my view to bother the UIthread.